# Find an analytic function that maps the angle $-\pi/4<\operatorname{arg}(z)<\pi/2$ onto the upper half plane so that $w(1-i)=2,w(i)=-1$, and $w(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an analytic function that maps the angle $-\pi/4<\operatorname{arg}(z)<\pi/2$  onto the upper half plane so that $w(1-i)=2$, $w(i)=-1$ , and $w(0)=0$

I'm trying to use this formula

$$\frac{w-w_1}{w-w_3 }\cdot\frac{w_2-w_3}{w_2-w_1 }=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_3 }\cdot\frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_1 }$$

so I got

$$\frac{w-2}{w-0 }\cdot\frac{-1-0}{-1-2 }=\frac{z-1+i}{z-0 }\cdot \frac{i-0}{i-1+i }$$
$$\frac{w-2}{w }\cdot\frac{1}{3 }=\frac{iz-i-1}{z(2i-1) }$$

$$w-2=3w\cdot\frac{iz-i-1}{z(2i-1) }$$

$$w(1-3\cdot\frac{iz-i-1}{z(2i-1) })=2$$
$$w=\frac{2z(2i-1)}{2iz-z-3iz+3i+3}$$

$$w=\frac{4iz-2z}{-iz-z+3i+3}$$
$$w=\frac{4iz-2z}{(3-z)(1+i)}$$

In order for this to be analytic, $z$ must not be $3$, but the angle $-π/4<\operatorname{arg}(z)<π/2$ also include $3$.

Now I follow the suggestion of GEdgar and tried the power of $z$. I know that $w=z^n$ always map the angle $\pi/n$ onto the upper half plane. In this problem my angle is between $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so the $arg(w)$ should be between $-n\pi/4$ and $n\pi/2$? and radius of $w$ is $r^n$ for $|z|=r$

Now plug into the function $w=z^n$ I got

$$(1-i)^n=2$$

$$i^n =-1$$

$$0^n=0$$

The last equation work for any $n$, the second equation implies that $n=2$ but the first equation I solve for $n$ and got $n= \ln (\frac{2}{1-i})$ but $n$ is the real number, right?

Actually, I don't have to worry about $n$ because $w=z^n$ is analytic for all $n$, but if this is true then why they have to give me $w(1-i)=2$, $w(i)=-1$ , and $w(0)=0$?

Comment: To change the angle at the corner, you will need to use a power of $z$.  Linear fractional transformations cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map
$$g(z):=\left(e^{i\pi/4} z\right)^{4/3}$$
maps the open wedge $W:\ -{\pi\over 4}<{\rm Arg}(z)<{\pi\over2}$ onto the upper half plane. The three points $i$, $0$, $1-i$ are lying on the boundary of $W$, but $g$ takes care of them as well. One computes
$$g(i)=-1, \quad g(0)=0,\quad g(1-i)=2^{2/3}\ .$$
Not all three points so obtained are  at the desired position. We therefore have to set up a Moebius transformation $T$ with
$$T:\quad\bigl(-1,0,2^{2/3}\bigr)\mapsto\bigl(-1,0,2\bigr)\ .$$
For this $T$ we can make the following "Ansatz":
$$T(z)={az\over d-z}\ .$$
(One has $b=0$ since $T(0)=0$; furthermore we may take $c=-1$ since $T$ cannot be a similarity.) Plugging in the correspondences $-1\mapsto -1$, $2^{2/3}\mapsto 2$
gives
$$a=2{1+2^{2/3}\over2-2^{2/3}}\doteq 12.5,\quad d=3{2^{2/3}\over 2-2^{2/3}}\doteq 11.54\ .$$
$T$ maps the real axis (incl. $\infty$) onto the real axis. Since $T'(0)={a\over d}>0$ the upper half-plane is mapped onto the upper half-plane, as desired. The $f$ you are looking for is then given by $f:=T\circ g$.

Comment: See my update. And (+1) because it looks good!

Comment: How did you find $g(z):=\left(e^{i\pi/4} z\right)^{4/3}$? I found a different $g:\ $ $g(z)=r^2e^{2i(\theta+\pi/4)}$

Comment: @Isa: We have to transform a $3\pi/4$ wedge into a half plane. This means that the angle at the vertex  has to be multiplied by $4/3$. Your $g$ multiplies this angle by $2$.Therefore the result would be a $3\pi/2$ sector.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer.** At the risk of giving a wrong answer - it will become apparent
at the bottom line why - nevertheless here comes. Something is wrong, either in the
question or in my answer. **My** question is, of course: where is the error?

The following is a related issue @ Mathematics Stack Exchange:

- [Applications of conformal mapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653021/applications-of-conformal-mapping)

And the main keyword is found @ Wikipedia as:

- [Schwarz–Christoffel mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping)

Using that theory we have for $-\pi/4<\operatorname{arg}(z)<\pi/2$ , at $z=0$ :
$$
\frac{dz}{dw} = K'(w-0)^{(\pi/2+\pi/4)/\pi-1} = K' w^{-1/4}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad z = K w^{3/4} + C 
$$
With $K = 4/3\cdot K'$. Substitute $z=0$ and $w=0$ herein and find that $C=0$.
Next step:
$$
i = K(-1)^{3/4} = K e^{i\,3\pi/4} = K/\sqrt{2}(-1+i)
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
K = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
It follows that:
$$
w(z) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\,z}{1-i}\right)^{4/3}
= \left(e^{i\pi/4} z\right)^{4/3} = g(z)
$$
Consequently:
$$
w(1-i) = \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{4/3} = 2^{2/3} \ne 2
$$
This is not consistent with the OP's question and it explains the above disclaimer.

**Update.** It seems that my wrong answer has served as an Ansatz
for the *correct answer* by Christian Blatter: $\,w(z) = T(g(z))$ ;
so it has served a purpose and I'm not going to delete it.
A contour plot of both $\,g(z)\,$ - on the left - and $\,T(g(z))\,$ - on the
right - shows the differences.
The viewports are $\,-0.1 < x < 1.9$ ,
$-1 < y < +1\,$ with $\,z = x+i\,y$ ; isolines of the Imaginary parts
are in $\color{red}{red}$ and isolines of the Real parts are in
$\color{green}{green}$ . Contour levels are between $-4$ and $+4$
with steps of $4/30$.

[image]

Comment: I got a similar result with $z^{4/3}$ but since it is not defined at $z=0$ I gave up.. I was also thinking there might be something wrong with the question..

Comment: quick question, what is an Ansatz?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Wikipedia answer: [Ansatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) .